# fill datatable from my sql for combobox

Tags: vb.net, combobox

```
 Private Sub type_km_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles type_km.SelectedIndexChanged
        If Not IsNothing(type_km.SelectedValue) Then
            Dim id As Integer = type_km.SelectedValue
            Call kon()
            koneksi.Open()
            cd = New MySqlCommand("SELECT no_kamar FROM km_hotel WHERE type_km='" & id & "' AND status='kosong' ORDER BY no_kamar ASC", koneksi)
            da = New MySqlDataAdapter(cd)
            dt = New DataTable
            da.Fill(dt)
            no_km.DisplayMember = "no_kamar"
            no_km.ValueMember = "no_kamar"
            no_km.DataSource = dt
        End If
    End Sub
```

where here i have 2 combobox

```
> combobox1 = type_km 
> combobox2 = no_km
```

and this is the header

```
> Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient Imports System.Threading
> 
> Public Class menu_utama
>     Public koneksi As MySqlConnection
>     Public da As MySqlDataAdapter
>     Public dt As DataTable
>     Public ds As DataSet
>     Public cd As MySqlCommand
>     Public rd As MySqlDataReader
> 
>     Private Sub kon()
>         koneksi = New MySqlConnection("Data Source=localhost ;user id=root; database=hotel;")
>         Try
>             koneksi.Open()
>             koneksi.Close()
>         Catch salah As Exception
>             MsgBox("Error koneksi database : " & salah.Message)
>         End Try
>     End Sub
```

i try combobox2 to display selected member of type_km in combobox1.

Anyone can solve , why its doesnt show the member of combobox1 on combobox2

Comment: `Dim adapter As DataSet` you dont have a DataAdapter.

Comment: revision, i have no error but my combobox doesnt show anything

Comment: no_km.DataBind() is missing. You set a source but never bind the object.